# Is an empty set smooth curve?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Consider the function $F:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ such that $F(x,y)=x^4+y^4+x^2-y^2$. The solution set (level set) of $F(x,y)=c$ where $c \in \mathbb R$ is called $X_c$. The definition for smooth curves are as follows:

> A subset $X_c \subset \mathbb R^2$ is a smooth ($C^1$) curve if for every point $(a,b) \in X_c$, there exist open neighborhoods $I$ of $a$ and $J$ of $b$, and either a $C^1$ mapping $f: I \to J$ or a $C^1$ mapping $g: J \to I$ (or both) such that $X_c \cap (I \times J)$ is the graph of $f$ or $g$.

For the above function, I have found that level set $X_c$ is a smooth curve as long as $c \neq 0$ and $c \neq-1/4$ (This is an example in Hubbard's multivariable calculus book, so I am not fabricating this). For all other $c$, the curve $X_c$ should be smooth. Geometrically, $X_c$ can be found by intersecting $F(x,y)=x^4+y^4+x^2-y^2$ and $z=c$ in three dimensions. Really, intersecting $F$ with $z=0$ yields an eight like curve which cannot be smooth around origin. However, considering the surface of $F(x,y)$:

[image]

we see that after some $c<0$ (I think after $c<-1/4$), there is no intersection between $F$ and $z=c$. So for some $c<0$, $X_c$ is an empty set. But my book tells and the theorem I have used predicts that $X_c$ is smooth for all $c$ excluding $c=0$ and $c=-1/4$. Since there are no other restrictions about the value of $c$, this means that empty sets are also smooth curves. But above definition doesn't say something like that.

**Can an empty set be considered as a smooth ($C^1$) curve or should we further restrict our choice of $c$?**

Comment: I would call an empty set (vacuously) smooth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By your definition, it is.

Empty set always satisfies $\forall x \in \emptyset ~P(x)$ for any $P$.